# List of journal abbreviations prints abbreviation instead of long journal title

Tags: biblatex, biber, acronyms

I'm using Biblatex' `DeclareSourceMap` and a `shortjournal` field in my `.bib` file to get abbreviated journal titles in citations. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}  
 \addbibresource{mwe.bib}  

  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%                                                
 \printfield{journaltitle}} 
   
\DeclareSourcemap{% 
\maps[datatype=bibtex]{ 
 \map[overwrite]{ 
 \step[fieldsource=shortjournal] 
 \step[fieldset=journaltitle,origfieldval] 
} } } 
\begin{document} 
   
 \section{First Section} 
 
 Here is a reference to an article with an abbreviated journal name\autocite{Herlin2008aa} 
 
 
\printbiblist[title={Journal Shorthands}]{shortjournal} 
\end{document}
```

Put this in mwe.bib:

```
@article{Herlin2008aa,
    author = {Herlin-Karnell, Ester},
    number = {10},
    pages = {1115 -- 1130},
    title = {What Principles Drive (or Should Drive) European Criminal Law?},
    volume = {11},
    date = {2008},
    journaltitle = {Common Market Law Review},
    shortjournal = {CMLRev.}
    }
```

This works, and what is particularly nice about it is that my bibliography style (oscola) takes this the value of `shortjournal` and strips any periods from it, exactly like it would do with the `journaltitle` string.

However, when printing a list of abbreviations, one column has the `shortjournal` value with periods and the other column has the `shortjournal` value without. What I want, of course, is for the second column to show the full journal title, in other words, the original value of `journaltitle` before it is affected by `DeclareSourceMap`.

From what I understand (complete novice...), `DeclareSourceMap` is applied first (see section 3.1.2. of the `Biber` manual). As a result, when I put

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
\printfield{journaltitle}}
```

in my preamble, the `journaltitle` has already been remapped.

So, how can I print the original value of `journaltitle` for the purposes of this list?

If this can't be done, wouldn't this mean that you can never create a list of journal abbreviations? After all, isn't `DeclareSoureMap` the standard way to use journal abbreviations in biblatex?

Comment: Questions like this are much, much easier to answer if they contain a small, yet fully compilable example document that shows a complete picture instead of just a few code snippets. (A so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.) Such an example document ensures we are all on the same page. From what I can tell so far I think what is going on is that the sourcemap irrevocably (at least from a `biblatex` perspective) overwrites the `journaltitle` with `shortjournal`. There is no way of getting it back. ...

Comment: ... You'd have to store `journaltitle` in another field or use a different approach altogether.

Comment: What kind of different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a sourcemap you essentially manipulate your entry data just when it is read from the `.bib` file. This means that for all intents and purposes overwriting `journaltitle` with `shortjournal` with a sourcemap means that `journaltitle` now contains the contents of the `shortjournal` field and that the old field value cannot be recovered on the `biblatex` side.

One solution would be to save the original `journaltitle` in a different field (say `longjournaltitle`, we need to declare this new field in a datamodel file) and use that when required in the list of journal shorthands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{longjournaltitle.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{longjournaltitle}

\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article,perioduical]{longjournaltitle}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=oscola, datamodel=longjournaltitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
  \printfield{longjournaltitle}}

\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, final]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldset=longjournaltitle, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle, origfieldval] 
    }
  }
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Herlin2008aa,
  author       = {Herlin-Karnell, Ester},
  number       = {10},
  pages        = {1115 -- 1130},
  title        = {What Principles Drive (or Should Drive) European Criminal Law?},
  volume       = {11},
  date         = {2008},
  journaltitle = {Common Market Law Review},
  shortjournal = {CMLRev.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for the MWE
Here is a reference to an article with an abbreviated journal name\autocite{Herlin2008aa}

\printbiblist[title={Journal Shorthands}]{shortjournal}
\end{document}
```

[image: CMLRev. Common Market Law Review]

---

Another solution would be not to remap the fields at all. Instead we instruct your style to print the `shortjournal` if available.

This is done by redefining the `journal` bibmacro from `biblatex.def`.

The sourcemap does not remap any fields any more, it just removes `.`s from the field (this is a copy of the sourcemap for `journaltitle` from `oscola.bbx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}}

\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
     \step[fieldsource=shortjournal,
           match=\regexp{(\d)\.(\d)},
           replace=\regexp{$1.$2}]
     \step[fieldsource=shortjournal,
           match=\regexp{(\D)\.(\d)},
           replace=\regexp{$1 $2}]
     \step[fieldsource=shortjournal,
            match=\regexp{\.(\D)},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
     \step [fieldsource=shortjournal,
            match=\regexp{(\D)\.},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
       and
       test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}
     }
       {}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}%
        \newunit}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitleaddon}
    {}
    {\printfield{journaltitleaddon}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Herlin2008aa,
  author       = {Herlin-Karnell, Ester},
  number       = {10},
  pages        = {1115 -- 1130},
  title        = {What Principles Drive (or Should Drive) European Criminal Law?},
  volume       = {11},
  date         = {2008},
  journaltitle = {Common Market Law Review},
  shortjournal = {CMLRev.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just for the MWE
Here is a reference to an article with an abbreviated journal name\autocite{Herlin2008aa}

\printbiblist[title={Journal Shorthands}]{shortjournal}
\end{document}
```

[image: CMLRev Common Market Law Review]